# Compact Framework, Custom TabControl, Designer interactions

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, compact-framework, visual-studio-designer

I'm considering making a custom TabControl for the Compact Framework 3.5, one that has Designer interactions enabled.

All my research so far has led me to solutions for a control targeting the full .Net Framework, and I have soon been stopped by the lack of several required classes, interfaces and namespaces in the Compact Framework.

Ideally, I would like to follow these tutorials, but I find myself unable to do so because of the aforementioned lack.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h51z5c0x(v=VS.90).aspx

I already have the .xmta file, and I am aware of the Designer tag, however I can't figure out which class to put in there since I can't figure out how to make that very class!

Any help on that matter would greatly be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't build custom, designable container controls for the CF, nor can you extend the existing TabControl and have designer support for it.

To be completely honest, though, I'd not use the TabControl at all for handheld development today.  For a longer diatribe on this, see [my reasoning and workaround here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2011/11/28/compact-framework-and-the-visual-studio-designer/).

Comment: I know this question is very old, but I've create my own advanced tab control in CF. There shouldn't be a reason you can't do it. Of course I extended Control not TabControl. As far as your article, it really depends on the device. We use a device with a large 8-10" screen, and my tab control is much prettier than the normal one. Also, you said that you cannot use the full framework for a designer, but actually you can do exactly that, without deploying it to the device. You create a separate design assembly, install it into the GAC, and then link to in the DesignTimeAttributes file.